# Storing and processing high data volume

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Good day!

I have 350GB unstructured data disaggregated by 50-80 columns.

I need to store this data in NoSQL database and do a variety of selection and map / reduce queries filtered by 40 columns.

I would like to use mongodb, so I have a certain question: is this database able to cope with this task and what do I need to implement its architecture within the existing provider hetzner.de?

Comment: yes, mongo is capable of doing that, 350GB of data is nothing for modern machines (few gigs of ram + multiple cores).

Comment: thx milan!
Use a single server or to build a cluster?

Comment: a single server for that data size is more than enough, but assuming offline processing.

Comment: Dear Milan, I want to waste on query not more than 60 seconds

Comment: I rest against at reading the disk 60 mb / sec == 350 * 1024 / 60 / 60 = 100 minutes per query ( if two or more query, too multiply by the number of requests )

Comment: mongodb uses memory mapped files, so after one scan you'll have the whole database in ram, so this number is not representative. second, you want every query to read the entire dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, large datasets are easy.

Perhaps [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is also worth looking at. It is aimed at handling/analyzing large/huge amounts of data.

Comment: Thx Steven!

I want to use a small number of servers, apache hadoop works fine with a large number of servers!

I think that I will have problems with map/reduce in apache hadoop because I do not work on java

Comment: I don't have any experience with Hadoop, but MongoDB is very easy to set up and play with. You can find a guide and some map/reduce examples on the MongoDB webpage.
If I find anything on Hadoop soon, I'll let you know.

Comment: Found it earlier than expected. See [this link](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html) for a MapReduce example in Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb is a very scalable and flexible database, if used properly. It can store as much data as you need, but the bottom line is whether you can query your data efficiently.

comments:

- You will need to make sure you have the proper indexes in place and that a fair amount of them can fit in RAM.
- In order to achieve that you may need to use sharding to split the working set
- current mapreduce is easy to use, can iterate over all your data but it is rather slow to process. It should become faster in next mongodb and there will also be a new aggregation framework to complement mapreduce.

Bottom line is that you should not take mongodb as a magical store that will be perfect out of the box, make sure you read the good docs and materials :)